# How to record the microphone untill there is no sound?

Tags: c++, winapi, voip, voice-recording

I've created 2 functions :
- One that records the microphone
- One that plays the sound of the microphone

It records the microphone for 3 seconds

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

 short int waveIn[44100 * 3];

void PlayRecord();

void StartRecord()
{
const int NUMPTS = 44100 * 3;   // 3 seconds
int sampleRate = 44100;  
// 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below
                         // for 8-bit capture, you'd use 'unsigned char' or 'BYTE' 8-bit     types

 HWAVEIN      hWaveIn;
 MMRESULT result;

 WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
 pFormat.wFormatTag=WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;     // simple, uncompressed format
 pFormat.nChannels=1;                    //  1=mono, 2=stereo
 pFormat.nSamplesPerSec=sampleRate;      // 44100
 pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec=sampleRate*2;   // = nSamplesPerSec * n.Channels *    wBitsPerSample/8
 pFormat.nBlockAlign=2;                  // = n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
 pFormat.wBitsPerSample=16;              //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
 pFormat.cbSize=0;

 // Specify recording parameters

 result = waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER,&pFormat,
        0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

  WAVEHDR      WaveInHdr;
 // Set up and prepare header for input
  WaveInHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
  WaveInHdr.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS*2;
  WaveInHdr.dwBytesRecorded=0;
  WaveInHdr.dwUser = 0L;
  WaveInHdr.dwFlags = 0L;
  WaveInHdr.dwLoops = 0L;
  waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

 // Insert a wave input buffer
  result = waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));


 // Commence sampling input
  result = waveInStart(hWaveIn);


 cout << "recording..." << endl;

  Sleep(3 * 1000);
 // Wait until finished recording

 waveInClose(hWaveIn);

 PlayRecord();
}

void PlayRecord()
{
const int NUMPTS = 44100 * 3;   // 3 seconds
int sampleRate = 44100;  
// 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below
                            // for 8-bit capture, you'd    use 'unsigned char' or 'BYTE' 8-bit types

HWAVEIN  hWaveIn;

WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
pFormat.wFormatTag=WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;     // simple, uncompressed format
pFormat.nChannels=1;                    //  1=mono, 2=stereo
pFormat.nSamplesPerSec=sampleRate;      // 44100
pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec=sampleRate*2;   // = nSamplesPerSec * n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
pFormat.nBlockAlign=2;                  // = n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
pFormat.wBitsPerSample=16;              //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
pFormat.cbSize=0;

// Specify recording parameters

waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER,&pFormat, 0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

WAVEHDR      WaveInHdr;
// Set up and prepare header for input
WaveInHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
WaveInHdr.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS*2;
WaveInHdr.dwBytesRecorded=0;
WaveInHdr.dwUser = 0L;
WaveInHdr.dwFlags = 0L;
WaveInHdr.dwLoops = 0L;
waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;
cout << "playing..." << endl;
waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &pFormat, 0, 0, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);
waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WaveInHdr)); // Playing the data
Sleep(3 * 1000); //Sleep for as long as there was recorded

waveInClose(hWaveIn);
waveOutClose(hWaveOut);
}

int main()
{
 StartRecord();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I change my StartRecord function (and I guess my PlayRecord function aswell), to make it record untill theres no input from the microphone?

(So far, those 2 functions are working perfectly - records the microphone for 3 seconds, then plays the recording)...

Thanks!

Edit: by no sound, I mean the sound level is too low or something (means the person probably isnt speaking)...

Comment: There is no such thing as "no sound".  Rather, the sound level drops below some threshold for some period of time.

Comment: Thats what I meant. so how can I check the sound level?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to write functions that record and play sound through WinAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741194/trying-to-write-functions-that-record-and-play-sound-through-winapi) by same poster.

Comment: @KenWhite It isnt, since in this thread, I was trying to split 1 function into 2, while here I'm trying to change it...

Comment: "start recording it, I'm saying a word into the microphone, and when theres a silence for a second or two it stops recording or something?" isn't the same as "make it record until there's no input from the microphone?"

Comment: Yes, it is the same...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because sound is a wave, it oscillates between high and low pressures.  This waveform is usually recorded as positive and negative numbers, with zero being the neutral pressure.  If you take the absolute value of the signal and keep a running average it should be sufficient.

The average should be taken over a long enough period that you account for the appropriate amount of silence.  A very cheap way to keep an estimate of the running average is like this:

```
const double threshold = 50;    // Whatever threshold you need
const int max_samples = 10000;  // The representative running average size

double average = 0;             // The running average
int sample_count = 0;           // When we are building the average

while( sample_count < max_samples || average > threshold ) {
    // New sample arrives, stored in 'sample'

    // Adjust the running absolute average
    if( sample_count < max_samples ) sample_count++;
    average *= double(sample_count-1) / sample_count;
    average += std::abs(sample) / sample_count;
}
```

The larger `max_samples`, the slower `average` will respond to a signal.  After the sound stops, it will slowly trail off.  However, it will be slow to rise again too.  This would be fine for reasonably continuous sound.

With something like speech, which can have short or long pauses, you may want to use an impulse-based approach.  You can just define the number of samples of 'silence' that you expect, and reset it whenever you receive an impulse that exceeds the threshold.  Using the running average above with a much shorter window size will give you a simple way of detecting an impulse.  Then you just need to count...

```
const int max_samples = 100;             // Smaller window size for impulse
const int max_silence_samples = 10000;   // Maximum samples below threshold
int silence = 0;                         // Number of samples below threshold

while( silence < max_silence_samples ) {
    // Compute running average as before

    //...

    // Check for silence.  If there's a signal, reset the counter.
    if( average > threshold ) silence = 0;
    else ++silence;
}
```

Adjusting `threshold` and `max_samples` will control the sensitivity to pops and clicks, while `max_silence_samples` gives you control over how much silence is allowed before you stop recording.

There are undoubtedly more technical ways to achieve your goals, but it's always good to try the simple one first.  See how you go with this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do it via DirectShow. You should create an instance of microphone, SampleGrabber, audio encoder and file writer. Your graph should be like this:

**Microphone -> SampleGrabber -> Audio Encoder -> File Writer**

Every sample passes through SampleGrabber and you can read all raw samples and check if you should continue record or not. This is the best way you and both record and check it's contents.

Comment: Writing to file -> opening to file to get the audio and play it on the computer is much much slower, especialy if I want to use it for VOIP...

Comment: It's all your choice. You can render it via Default DirectSound Device, or render it to Null Renderer, or write it to file, or etc. It's all your choice. I suggested you to write to file because your code does this.

Comment: My code isnt writing into file, the playing function gets the buffer and plays it, making it much faster...

Comment: Sorry Amit, I read it wrong. Well, you can still render it: Microphone -> SampleGrabber -> Default DirectSound Device. You can pause/start/stop the graph as you wish.

Comment: Thanks! but is there an option in DirectShow, like using the WINAPI Wave functions, to record and play it through buffer?

Comment: If you don't want to have/carry extra library, don't worry because you won't. DirectShow was part of DirectX SDK and moved to Windows SDK. Everything you use from DirectShow exists on typical Windows machine (like quartz.dll). By the way, recording to memory is not a good choice because raw wav are bulky. But I told you, you can control everything on your own. You can pause/play/stop, you can get samples using SampleGrabber. You can even create your own DirectShow filter and do whatever you want. Believe me, DirectShow is vast and powerful area for these functions.

Comment: By the way, you can test your graph using GrahpEdit which can be found at your "%windowsSDK%\bin\graphedt.exe". GraphEdit is so easy to use.